# Can I return a Stream to the user and write to it as the data is generated on the server side

Tags: c#, wcf, download, zip

I have a WCF webservice that builds projects and allows them through be downloaded through a webinterface.

When a build has never been downloaded before the service zips the folder and returns the zip file, if it has been downloaded before the zip file already exists and can be downloaded without waiting for it to be zipped.

Since the zip process can be time consuming for some builds I'd like to be able to return a Stream to the user as soon as he makes the request, and start writing the zip file data to it as it is generated. (More user friendly in my opinion) Would something like this be possible?

Note: I'm currently using System.IO.Compression for zipping, but I'm open to use another library like dotnetzip if this would make the task easier/possible.

My current code is here:

```
public Stream DownloadBuildOutput(string BuildID)
    {
        noCaching();
        int Buildid;
        string InputFolder = null ;
        string OutputName;
        string OutputPath;
        if (Int32.TryParse(BuildID, out Buildid))
        {
            InputFolder = DatabaseManager.GetBuildLocation(Buildid);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new WebFaultException<string>("Argument for DownloadBuildOutput must be an Integer.", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        if (InputFolder != null)
        {
            OutputName = InputFolder.Substring(InputFolder.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1) + ".zip";
            OutputPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Workingfolder"] + "\\" + OutputName;
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Set("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + OutputName);
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
            if (new FileInfo(OutputPath).Exists)
            {
                FileStream exists = File.OpenRead(OutputPath);
                return exists;
            }

            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(InputFolder, OutputPath);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new WebFaultException<string>("Could not find Build Location. Make sure the build exists and finished successfully.", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest); 
        }

        return File.OpenRead(OutputPath);

    }
```

Edit: Using Peter Duniho's comment I have come a bit further, I created a ZipArchive as such and launched a new thread to write information to it while my worker thread returned the stream:

```
output = File.Open(OutputPath,FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(output, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);
DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(InputFolder);
new ZipThread(dirinfo, archive, output);
return output;
```

and my zipthread class looks like this:
public class ZipThread
    {
        private FileSystemInfo fileSystem;
        private ZipArchive ziparchive;
        private Stream stream ;

```
    public ZipThread(DirectoryInfo folder, ZipArchive archive, Stream stream)
    {
        this.ziparchive = archive ;
        this.fileSystem = folder;
        this.stream = stream ;
        ThreadStart threadstart = new ThreadStart(CreateArchive);
        Thread thread = new Thread(threadstart) ;
        thread.IsBackground = true ;
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void CreateArchive()
    {
        WriteZipFileFromDir(ziparchive, fileSystem);
        stream.Close() ;
        stream.Dispose() ;
    }

    private void WriteZipFileFromDir(ZipArchive archive, FileSystemInfo fileSystemInfo)
    {
        var directoryInfo = fileSystemInfo as DirectoryInfo;
        if (directoryInfo != null)
        {
            foreach (var childInfo in directoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos())
            {
                WriteZipFileFromDir(archive, childInfo);
            }
        }

        if ( fileSystemInfo is FileInfo )
        {
            string entryname = fileSystemInfo.FullName.Substring((System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Workingfolder"] + "\\").Length) ;
            archive.CreateEntryFromFile(fileSystemInfo.FullName, entryname);
        }
    }
}
```

I now get a System.ArgumentException "Stream was not writable" at the line `archive.CreateEntryFromFile(fileSystemInfo.FullName, entryname);`

Comment: The usual answer to the question _"Would something like this be possible"_ is "well, what happened when you **tried** it?" It's been a few years since I wrote WCF code that returned a `Stream` object, but my recollection is that it was possible to write to the stream that was being read by the remote end. But really, you should just try it. `ZipArchive` should work fine for the scenario, since it can write a stream in non-seek mode as long as the archive is created in `Create` mode instead of `Update`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't because the file is only sent to the user when you use one of the following :

- HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
- HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
- HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("yourFile.zip");

As a workaround, you can use AJAX so the user can still use your application while the file is being created and downloaded.

You could also try to following code :
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/812406